# How far is the far plane in an ARKit session?

Tags: arkit

So,

I have been using the unproject function on the SCNSceneRenderer:

```
public func unprojectPoint(_ point: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3
```

When I want to unproject a screen point I pass in Z = 1.

To check on things I also placed a node in the scene at the unprojected vector position. Things seem to check out.

In the process I have wondered about how ARKit really handle the near and far plane.

The unprojected point on the far plane when logged gives me this, and this is when I point the camera (as straight as possible downtime -Z in world coordinates):

```
SCNVector3(x: 121.191811, y: -176.614227, z: -1111.88794)
```

Given that in ARKit the unit is meters, does -1111 mean that the far plane is about 1K away?

I am trying to understand how the near and far planes are positioned in an ARKit session, specifically, is the far plane at a fixed position, meaning, is it always at a fixed distance from the camera? Does it change? And is that about 1K meters seem to make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unprojectPoint` function uses the same projection as the camera. If you want to know what the camera projection’s near and far planes are, ask the view for its [`pointOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview) node, ask that node for its [`camera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407976-camera), and ask the camera for its [`zNear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436592-znear) and [`zFar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436596-zfar) settings.

Comment: Doing that gives me these values: zNEAR = 0.00100000004749745, zFAR = 1000.0. does that mean the zFar is 1Km away? Is this correct?

Comment: Yep. 1/1000 to 1000 scene-space units (regardless of what they map to in real-world terms) is typical for a lot of 3D renderer setups, and encompasses just about all the sensible AR use cases. Note that this is all SceneKit stuff — not specific to ARKit.

Comment: so, I think then I need to mark your answer as correct, and create a new question worded properly. My main objective here is to know how far in terms of "meters" the planes are, mainly the far plane. So, is there a way to compute that from the 1/1000 SceneKit information we got here?

Comment: So, how does the comment you made here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558540/what-unit-is-used-by-the-scene-editor-in-xcode affect what it's being discussed on this question. On that answer you said "When used with ARKit, SceneKit lengths/distances are in meters" .... so, I am confused then what 10000.0 really means here.

Comment: also see this comment on that same page: Got feedback from Apple regarding the missing unit displayed: "The basic unit in SceneKit is always the meter and it cannot be changed so you can always assume it to be the case."

Comment: Yes, the code you used indicates the far plane is 1 km away.